# Will this be a non-interference in a multi-threaded environment?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, deque, thread-synchronization

```
std::deque<T> dq;
Thread_function(pointer to queue as argument)     // created 8 threads
{
     vertext_found = true;
     **v is initialized to NULL
     while ( i < dq->size())
     {
          EnterCriticalSection(&h);
          if( i < dq.size() ) {
              v = dq.at(i);      // accessing element of queue without popping
              i++;
              vertext_found = true;
          }
          LeaveCriticalSection(&h);
          if (vertext_found && (i < dq.size()) && v != NULL)
          {
              **operation on 'v'
              vertext_found = false;
          }
     }
}
```

Will this be a data race condition especially when processing "**while ( i < dq->size())**" outside the Critical Section? Is my approach correct? Otherwise plz suggest me.

Comment: Is `std::deque<T> dq;` really meant to be a local object? I see you are accessing it as if it was a pointer (`dq->size()`)

Comment: It looks like you are only ever reading from the queue. Is that correct?

Comment: Post a more complete example.  You are leaving out too much information.  Your dq appears to be thread local but your question implies it isn't.

Comment: If dq is shared between threads then please explain whether you modify it in parallel with accessing or not. If you have 8 threads that only reading the queue without modifications, then you don't need sync at all..

Comment: i am just reading the queue.. but need to access each element by different thread.. yes i am passing pointer to queue

Answer (score 4):

> Will this be a non-interference in a multi-threaded environment?

In your question's text, `dq` (like all the other variables in your function) is a *local* object:

```
std::deque<T> dq;
```

If this is really the case, then the question has an easy answer: **"Yes"**. It is thread-safe because there is no contention: each thread works on a local object, and since there is no sharing, there can't be any data race.

---

Now assuming that your code intended to show the use of a *shared* data structure, and that `dq` is actually a global object or something somehow accessible by several threads simultaneously (this is what the `dq->size()` function call seems to suggest), then the answer is **"It depends"**.

**If all of your threads are concurrently executing only the function you are showing, and `dq` is a reference or pointer to `const`**, so that your function doesn't contain any call to any non-`const` member functions, then the answer is **"Yes, *but*** you don't really need *any* critical section at all in this case". Paragraph 17. 6.5.9/3 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects (1.10) accessible by threads
>   other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s non-`const`
>   arguments, including `this`.

The reference to Paragraph 1.10 (and in particular to 1.10/21), which defines what a data races is, makes the meaning of the above Paragraph clearer:

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two **conflicting actions** in different threads,
>   at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in
>   undefined behavior. [...]

Finally, Paragraph 1.10/4 specifies when two actions are conflicting:

> Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location (1.7) and the other one
>   accesses or modifies the same memory location.

What follows from all this is that **`const` member functions are necessarily thread-safe**. You may be interested in watching [this presentation by Herb Sutter](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank) about it.

Since `deque<T>::size()` is a `const` member function, and `at()` is a `const` member function (because you are calling it from a reference or pointer to `const`) which returns a reference to `const`, there is no need to synchronize access from multiple threads.

---

**If your `dq` is *not* a reference or pointer to `const`**, then the answer is "**No**", because `at()` is a non-`const` member function. Moreover, since `v` is a non-const reference to an element, your "operation on `v`" could be non-`const`, therefore introducing a data-race on the *elements* of `dq` rather than on `dq` itself.

Similarly, **if your threads are concurrently accessing and modifying `dq` through other functions**, then the answer is again **"No"**, because you are not protecting all the accesses to the shared object. Read operations conflict with write operations (see above), and you are only protecting *some* of them. In this case, your critical section should span the entire `while` cycle.

Comment: @Andy.. edited my original post.. I am not modifying(deleting or writing) the queue. I am just accessing/reading elements of queue. But no two threads should access the same element of the queue. Sometimes the program executes fine but sometimes getting "access violation reading location error" at "**operation on 'v'". What might be the problem?

Comment: @Hello: Are you just accessing those elements? Or are you modifying them? If you are just accessing them, then all the `const` functions should be thread-safe, which means you can let `dq` be a reference or pointer to `const`. In that case, you need no critical section at all. If you are modifying those elements, then the critical section should wrap the "operation on v" as well. Notice, that since you are never modifying the queue, the redundant `if (i < dq.size())` is useless.